# Django - runserver error

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

beginner here. I have no clue how to solve it (errors are in attached image). Tried to implement solutions for similar errors posted, but none worked.

[ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7GVC.png)

Comment: btw got Windows 10, Python 3.5.1, Django 1.9.4

Comment: Can you include the image in your post?

Comment: I can't understand how a question with no code, linking to a *picture* of errors on an external site, got an upvote.

Comment: Upvotes are serious business, right?

Also, all uploaded images are reuploaded to imgur via stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gethostbyaddr()` throws an `UnicodeDecodeError` because your Windows hostname contains non-UTF-8 characters.

You'll have to remove those characters from your hostname to get Django running.